# What can we say about $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^{m^s}= ?$ for $|r|<1.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know the geometric series:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^{m}= \frac{r}{1-r}$$ for $|r|<1.$

(Please correct me if I've made mistake.)

> My question is: For fix $s>0,$
>   What can we say about $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^{m^s}= ?$$ for $|r|<1.$

Comment: Actually,$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty r^m=\frac r{1-r}.$$

Comment: @Jose. Ok, got it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hopeless to expect a closed form when $s \neq 1$. Still, we may extract some properties of the sum. For instance, if $s > 0$ and $r \in (0, 1)$, then by writing $\epsilon = -\log r$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^{m^s}
= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} e^{-\epsilon m^s}
= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \int_{\epsilon m^s}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{x \geq \epsilon m^s\}} \right) e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now by writing

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{x \geq \epsilon m^s\}}
= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{m \leq (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} \}}
= \sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} \rfloor} 1
= \lfloor (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} \rfloor
\end{align*}

and plugging this back, we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^{m^s}
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lfloor(x/\epsilon)^{1/s}\rfloor e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

(If you are familiar with Stieltjes integral, you can obtain this integral representation quite easily as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} e^{-\epsilon m^s}
= \int_{(0,\infty)} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}\lfloor (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} \rfloor
=  \int_{0}^{\infty} \lfloor(x/\epsilon)^{1/s}\rfloor e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}

where the second step follows from integration by parts.) Without the flooring function, we would get

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s})}{\epsilon^{1/s}}
\end{align*}

by using the gamma function. Instead, using the inequality $x-1 \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s})}{\epsilon^{1/s}} - 1
\leq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} e^{-\epsilon m^s}
\leq \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s})}{\epsilon^{1/s}}
\end{align*}

for $r \in (0, 1)$ and $s > 0$. From this we may extract some asymptotic behavior of the sum. Similar argument shows that, if $s$ is a positive integer and $r \in (0, 1)$, then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-r)^{m^s}
= - \int_{0}^{\infty} (\lfloor(x/\log(1/r))^{1/s}\rfloor \text{ mod } 2) e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
\xrightarrow[\text{as } r\uparrow 1]{} -\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I know that this kind of comments are not permitted in this site, but I must to say it: amazing answer. There is still some free place in your fan's club, mr Lee?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to figure,  how does this follows $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{m \leq (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} \}}
= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m \mathbf{1}_{\{m \leq (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} < m+1 \}}$ and why this  equals 
 $\lfloor (x/\epsilon)^{1/s} \rfloor$? I'm also interested in the proof of  $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \lfloor(x/\epsilon)^{1/s}\rfloor e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s})}{(\log(1/r))^{1/s}} + \mathcal{O}(1)$ ?  Where should I look at for  this? Please would you tell me bit more?

Comment: Last, my understating  is , from your answer,  for $0<r<1, s>0$, we can say: $ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^{m^s}
\leq \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{s})}{(\log(1/r))^{1/s}} + C$ (where $C$ is some constant independent of  $r$ and $s$), am I correct?

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you! In fact, my answer is motivated from a fairly straightforward approach (approximating sum by integral in a systematical way).

Comment: @MathLearner I modified my answer. Hope this answers your questions :)